# What is the variable between parenthesis and the arrow (->) in a Java lambda?

Tags: java, lambda

The IDE's recommended fix generated code like the following.

```
    col1.setCellValueFactory(
            (Callback<CellDataFeatures<String, String>, ObservableValue<String>>) param ->
                    new SimpleObjectProperty<>(param.getValue().getValue())
    );
```

I do not understand the `param` between `ObservableValue<String>>)` and `->`. Is there a hint like what this is called so that I can search the web for more details about this type of code?

Below are the signatures of the methods and interface.

```
void setCellValueFactory(Callback<TreeTableColumn.CellDataFeatures<S, T>, ObservableValue<T>> var1)

public interface Callback<P, R> {
    R call(P var1);
}
```

---

PS: Since some person told me to specify `col1`, it is an object of the [TreeTableColumn](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TreeTableColumn.html) class in JavaFX.

I think I was deceived by the parentheses and the `param`'s not having parenthesis, and thought those in the parentheses were the parameters. I had expected a form like [below](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lambda-expressions-java-8/).

[image]
 On close inspection, the code inside the parentheses is just type declarations, not variables... And it seems that parentheses for parameters can be omitted when there is only one parameter.

Comment: `param` is a parameter. You're turning that lambda into a `Callback` object, which is a functional interface

Comment: that is actually a SAM Conversion, param in actually var1 defined in interface Callback<P, R>. You're passing an implementation of callback overriding the call function into the setCellValueFactory().

Comment: @AnimeshSahu Java kinda dropped SAMs and only uses lambdas for functional interfaces, not abstract classes with a single abstract method

Comment: show please the definition of `col1`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`param` is the parameter that is being passed on to lambda. This code will help you understand what is happening:

```
Function<String,String> s = (Function<String,String>) param -> {
    System.out.println(param);
    return param;
};
s.apply("Hello World");
```

This above code is unnecessarily casting the lambda to `(Function<String, String>)`.

If you change it to `(Function<String,Long>)`, you will get compile time error.

Answer (score 0):

You asked what `param` was and whether it could be searched on.  You also asked about the "form" of the lambda expression (why parenthesis are present or not).  My answer below addresses those questions.

Searching for the text `param` will not usually work as the text `param` is arbitrary... you could replace it with `p` or even `arbitraryName` and as long as the name on the right of the `->` in the lambda expression changes to the same value the code should still work.

You can think of `param` as the name given to a "passed in" parameter.  In the method declaration below there are two parameters (`param` and `anotherParam`).

```
    public void myPrint(String param, String anotherParam) {
        System.out.println(param+", "+anotherParam);
    }
```

A lambda expression is like a method declaration (like the above) but unneeded text can be removed in the syntax of the lambda expression.  If the above **COULD** be made into a Lambda expression it would look like the following:

```
    (String param, String anotherParam) -> { System.out.println(param+", "+anotherParam); }
```

Notice how similar the lambda expression is to the method declaration. Notice also that the text "myPrint" does not appear in the above.  A lambda expression can be thought of as a "nameless" method declaration.  In Java, a lambda expression is providing the code to implement a SingleAbstractMethod (SAM) in an an interface that only has a single abstract method defined.  Assuming you had an interface with "MyPrint" defined as the name of the SAM then "MyPrint" is not needed (it is the only abstract method in the interface).  Lambda Expressions work because a SAM Interface is a "Functional Interface" and lambda expressions implement the SAM in a functional interface.  In a lambda expression the method name that you are implementing is ALWAYS not needed.  This is one of the things that makes lambda expressions hard to understand as you normally understand a method by its name (to some degree) and you would like to search on the method name the lambda expression is implementing but that name does not appear in the lambda code.

The code above could also be written as...

```
 (param, anotherParam) -> { System.out.println(param+", "+anotherParam); }
```

if the Java Type system can figure out the parameter types (in this case `String`) for itself.  Again, the names `param` and `anotherParam` are arbitrary but their types are not.  They are defined by the SAM in the functional interface you are implementing with the lambda.  Another reason lambdas are hard to understand is the type of the parameter(s) is often interesting... but it is often left off from the lambda expression as it is not always needed by Java.

If there was only one parameter needed by the SAM the lambda expression could be written like the following

```
 (String param) -> { System.out.println(param); }
```

or if "String" could be determined by Java

```
 (param) -> { System.out.println(param); }
```

or even the `()` are not needed in this last version

```
 param -> { System.out.println(param); }
```

There are other simplifications as well.  In some cases the `{}` on the right side of the `->` can be removed if it is only a single statement or expression.

If there are no parameters in the SAM being implemented then the code `() ->` is used where `()` signifies no parameters.

The last thing that I'll mention that is hard to understand about a lambda expression is the large number of syntax simplifications that can be made (see all the above).  This appears to be the majority of your confusion.

**Bottom Line:** a lambda expression can be thought of as a nameless method declaration where you are overriding a SAM in a functional interface.  The left hand side of the `->` are the parameter declarations... the parameter types and even the `()` are not always needed.  The right hand side of the `->` is the body of the method and in some cases the `{}` are not needed.

Keys to understanding a lambda expression is understanding the syntax (all the above forms) and determining and understanding the functional interface and SAM that is being implemented.  Unfortunately neither the functional interface or the name of the SAM show up in the lambda expression syntax itself... it is simplified away as not being needed!